# Issue with Twitter and LinkedIn meta tags with Cloudfront & Lambda@Edge

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, server-side-rendering, meta-tags

I'm using a Lambda@Edge function (triggered on origin request) to change the meta tags for a react site, hosted on S3 with Cloudfront, for rich social sharing. It works perfectly for Facebook, but doesn't for Twitter or LinkedIn.

LinkedIn errors (from their post inspector):

- We encountered a server error while trying to inspect the URL.
- (URL Redirect Trail) 500 Failure

and Twitter card validator error:

- INFO:  Page fetched successfully
- INFO:  11 metatags were found
- ERROR: No card found (Card error)

I believe my tags are actually ok e.g. Facebook's sharing debugger shows what it sees:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@myTwitter">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@myTwitter">
<meta name="description" content="My amazing content">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://mys3bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/media/myImage.19c87b8d.jpg">
<meta property="og:title" content="My amazing title">
<meta property="og:description" content="My amazing content">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/whatever/mypage">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US">
<meta name="author" content="me">
```

My question is - is Cloudfront the issue i.e. could it be stopping the Twitterbot / however LinkedIn does it? I have ran:

curl -A TwitterBot https://www.example.com

and it does return html with the correct tags, so I'm not sure.

If I turn off the Lambda@Edge and just hard-code the same meta tags into my html.index, Twitter and LinkedIn sharing work fine.

I can't see anything in the AWS docs of anything I should be doing to allow Twitter/LinkedIn bots.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I'm curious how you're achieving this given that Lambda@Edge doesn't expose the response body.  Are you fullscale replacing the body with new, updated, html?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this - my issue was that when I was replacing the meta tags in the Lambda function, I wasn't specifying a Content-Type header in the response.

So:

```
const responseHeaders = {
    'content-type': [{key:'Content-Type', value: 'text/html'}],
};
```

and after adding that to the response, social sharing on LinkedIn & Twitter worked.